# Question about a sentence in a song

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, reduced-relative-clauses

> I was stranded on an island
> where I ran without direction. Is that the wind lifting me up?

So my problem is with the last one, I would understand it completely if it were: "Is that the wind that is lifting me up?" Was "that is" omitted here (for the sake of the song) or this sentence does have another meaning?

Comment: Yes, _that is_ is omitted - not for the sake of the song, but because it's common to do so. "This is Mary speaking." "Is that the baby crying?"

Comment: @KateBunting Is this gramatically correct and can be used in formal writing as well ? Or just spoken english

Comment: Yes, I intended to imply that it was grammatically correct and a part of standard English.

Comment: This is sometimes called [Whiz deletion](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=24650) and is a perfectly normal part of English.

Comment: @ColinFine Does this apply to any relative clause that has (who-which-that, etc...) and "Be"?

Comment: I don't about **any** relative clause with "be", but certinaly it is general - see the blog I linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author has performed what is known as "relative clause reduction" on the second sentence. It did *not* change the meaning; it merely said the same thing but in a slightly more concise, and aesthetically pleasing way.

So, written in full, it would have had the "that is" as you described:

> Is that the wind that is lifting me up?

where *"that is lifting me up"* is the relative clause. The author has quite validly chopped out the relative pronoun, "that". To be honest, I'm not exactly sure what part of the speech the "is" is taking here, but it had to be removed too in order for the reduction to work and to produce the final:

> Is that the wind lifting me up?

More details at [EnglishGrammar.org](https://www.englishgrammar.org/reduced-relative-clauses/).

Incidentally, the use of relative cause reduction is part of what makes the famous, ["Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo) example work!

Comment: Can I do this to any relative clause ? I mean, Instead of saying "John is a boy who is happy" I say "John is a boy happy". I think this is very strange, At least for me a non-native speaker

Comment: In that particular example, no you cannot do the reduction; so you are right to see it as strange. The correct way to shorten the original would be simply to use, "John is a happy boy" (although there are circumstances where that might convey a subtle change in meaning). But unfortunately, I can't explain *why* it doesn't work in this case. You might want to ask precisely that as a full question (rather than just in a comment).  I'd be interested to see the answer! 

Answer (score 1):

Both participles "lifting me up" and relative clauses "that is lifting me up" can be used as modifiers of nouns. And the meaning is roughly the same.  This can be done in prose as well as song.

> I saw John playing tennis.

> I saw John who was playing tennis.